# Equivalence of $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}f(z)$ and Cauchy-Riemann equations

Tags: complex-analysis

I am looking at the problem 2 in [this homework](http://www.math.wustl.edu/~victor/classes/ma416/s02.pdf).

The problem that I am having is the transition between $\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right](u + iv)$ to $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$

I think that the formula in the exercise might be wrong, otherwise I am a little lost. Should it rather be $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}} = \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right]$ (note an extra $i$ inside brackets)?

Thank you in advance for your clarification!

Igor

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the formula (just corrected), there was one minus sign I missed. So, I think that this minus sign is the result of $i^2$, and I shouldn't have it inside the brackets... Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your correction, I am getting

$$\frac 1 2\left[ {\frac{\partial }{{\partial x}} + i\frac{\partial }{{\partial y}}} \right](u + iv) =\frac 1 2\left( \frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial x}} + i\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial y}} + i\frac{{\partial v}}{{\partial x}} - \frac{{\partial v}}{{\partial y}}\right)$$

which seems to be what the author intended.

Comment: So, I guess it is a typo... Thank you, Peter!